# Where is machineKey/validationKey used in FormsAuthentication?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, machinekey

[MSDN : machineKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.machinekey(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Configures algorithms and keys to use for encryption, decryption, and validation of forms-authentication data and view-state data, and for out-of-process session state identification

Specifically which methods in FormsAuthentication make use of validationKey and encryptionKey values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The methods in FormsAuthentication that use `validationKey` and `encryptionKey` are the [FormsAuthentication.Encrypt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.encrypt.aspx) and [FormsAuthentication.Decrypt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.decrypt.aspx) methods.

Comment: thanks. are those the only methods that make direct use of those two configuration settings?

Comment: @qntmred: I call `Encrypt` directly before setting the cookie which I guess I do it because `SetCookie` does not encrypt automatically. But perhaps I am doing it unnecessarily if `SetCookie` already does it behind the scenes. I suggest you try calling `SetCookie` without calling `Encrypt` explicitly and check whether the cookie created is encrypted or not. That's an easy enough test.

Comment: @qntmred: I just checked the implementation of `FormsAuthentication` class using ILSpy and `SetCookie` does not `Encrypt` automatically; however, `GetAuthCookie` does call `Encrypt`. You should download ILSpy and do the same I did. It will clarify all your doubts. http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx

Comment: i had used JustDecompile to look around System.Web.dll, but unless I missed it, there's no feature to find ALL references to `MachineKey.ValidationKey` and you have to find them manually, which means it's likely I missed somewhere it would be used